# How to automate the text file preparation in powerbuilder

Tags: automation, sybase, powerbuilder

Previously we used to prepare a text file manually by referring to some column values in a table. Now we have to include this as a utility in one of our applications through powerbuilder. So can you please give me some ideas to do that.

Comment: "Previously we used to prepare a text file manually by referring to some column values in a table"  What does this mean?  What is the nature of your question? How to create a text file?

Comment: Yes. How to create a tab seperated text file by taking the values from a datawindow.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your reply to my comment you can use the dw.Saveas method.

dw.Saveas('C:\temp\myfile.csv',CSV!,FALSE) for just the values in the datawindow. If you need the column heading change the last parameter to 'TRUE'.